# How can I dynamically determine which column is passed to friendly_id in order to watch it for changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm using the very useful option:

```
# config/initializers/friendly_id.rb

# ...
config.use Module.new {
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.blank?
  end
}
```

The issue is that I use friendly_id on 3 or 4 different models for which the attribute to watch for a change is differrent. For some it's `name`, others `title`. Is there a way to dynamically retrieve the attribute symbol that was passed to `friendly_id :title, use: :slugged` to prevent this being necessary in models?

```
# app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    super || title_changed?
  end
end
```

```

Ideally I'm looking for something like:

```
# config/initializers/friendly_id.rb

# ...
config.use Module.new {
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.blank? || friendly_id_attribute_changed?
  end
}
```

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Please tag your questions properly: this question has almost nothing to do with core ruby, while tagging it with `rails` seems mandatory.